# Xrandr problem trying to avoid broken display

Tags: linux, xrandr, display, monitors

Days ago I broke my laptop display by accident, the right side of the screen is damaged, but the most part of the left side is usable. I did some research trying to find a way to modify the dimension of the screen to fit into the area with no damage and I found `xrandr`.

[image: screenshot]

I found the next .sh archive but I can't find a way to put the screen into the left side, neither modifying the --transform parameters or the `--fb` command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#change these 4 variables accordingly
ORIG_X=1280
ORIG_Y=800
NEW_X=1160
NEW_Y=800
###

X_DIFF=$(($NEW_X - $ORIG_X))
Y_DIFF=$(($NEW_Y - $ORIG_Y))

ORIG_RES="$ORIG_X"x"$ORIG_Y"
NEW_RES="$NEW_X"x"$NEW_Y"
ACTIVEOUTPUT=$(xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/")
MODELINE=$(cvt $NEW_X $NEW_Y | grep Modeline | cut -d' ' -f3-)

xrandr --newmode $NEW_RES $MODELINE
xrandr --addmode $ACTIVEOUTPUT $NEW_RES
xrandr --output $ACTIVEOUTPUT --fb $NEW_RES --panning $NEW_RES --mode $NEW_RES
xrandr --fb $NEW_RES --output $ACTIVEOUTPUT --mode $ORIG_RES --transform 1,0,$X_DIFF,0,1,$Y_DIFF,0,0,1
```

I also tried to do it without the .sh archive running the next line:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --fb 800x768 --mode 800x768 --transform 1,0,566,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

The screen took the position I want but after running that command a black border on the left side of the screen appears and I can't remove it.

[image: screenshot]

Any idea of what it's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the screen size with `xrandr --fb` (no `--mode`, `--transform`, whatever).

```
$ xrandr --fb 800x768
```

`xrandr` will complain about the screen size being too small, but will apply the settings nonetheless.

Example:

```
$ xrandr --fb 1520x1080
xrandr: specified screen 1520x1080 not large enough for output VGA-0 (1920x1080+0+0)
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43

# from the xtruss output
--- ConfigureNotify(event=w#000004A8, window=w#000004A8, x=0, y=0, width=1520, height=1080, border-width=0, above-sibling=None, override-redirect=False)

$ xwininfo -root | grep geo
  -geometry 1520x1080+0+0
```

That should probably be a warning rather than an error; there are situations where it makes perfect sense to set the screen size to something smaller than the actual display(s).

**Update:**

Multi-head enabled window managers get the info about the screen(s) via the Xrandr(3) and Xinerama(3) extensions, and do not clamp their dimensions inside the root window rectangle.

A temporary workaround would be to prevent them from using the `Xrandr` and `Xinerama` extensions via a `LD_PRELOAD` hack. That could be improved by turning the dummy functions into wrappers that trim the returned rectangles.

This worked for me on vanilla debian 9.5 with the `mate` desktop environment and either the `lightdm` or `gdm3` display manager:

```
root# apt-get install mate-desktop-environment lightdm
root# apt-get install gcc

root# cat <<'EOT' | cc -fPIC -x c - -shared -o /etc/X11/no_xrr.so
int XineramaIsActive(void *d){ return 0; }
void *XineramaQueryScreens(void *dpy, int *n){ *n = 0; return 0; }
int XineramaQueryExtension(void *d, int *i, int *j){ return 0; }
int XRRQueryExtension(void *d, int *i, int *j){ return 0; }
EOT

root# cat <<'EOT' >/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98-no_xrr
export LD_PRELOAD=/etc/X11/no_xrr.so
case $STARTUP in
/usr/bin/ssh-agent*)
        STARTUP="/usr/bin/ssh-agent env LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD ${STARTUP#* }";;
esac
EOT
```

Then, from the session menu of `lightdm` choose "MATE", and as the logged-in user:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD= xrandr --fb 800x768
```

I wasn't able to get it to work though with either `plasma` or `gnome3`/`gnome-shell`/`mutter` yet.

Comment: I tried to do that before, the problem is --fb just shrink the usable dimension of the screen to x and y values but it doesn't set the current size of the screen to that values. In another words, the half of the screen get unreachable using that command. https://imgur.com/a/bOCHrqI there you can see that the half of the screen has been cut using --fb, the rest of the screen is dark.

Comment: should the broken part of the screen be "reachable"? how? And the command really does set the size of the screen to those values -- look at the `xtruss` and `xwininfo` output; and the new size was readily picked by the window manager. What window manager are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the dimension of the entire screen to fit into the no damage area, when I use --fb XxY I get something like this https://imgur.com/a/1uszcyd the idea is reduce the dimension to see the entire window like this https://imgur.com/a/udSwTTl but smaller (smaller enough to be able to see it into the no damage area of my display). I don't know what is a window manager, any help?

Comment: What system / distribution is that? As to [wm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager), that's a program like compiz, xfwm. It should handle the change in the root window size automatically. Could you please run the `xwininfo -root` command in a terminal and post the output?

Comment: It's Debian 9.5 amd64 with desktop environment Gnome3. Here is the result of `xwininfo -root` https://imgur.com/a/nInQd8P after run `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --fb 820x768` this is the result https://imgur.com/a/AaZzXix nonetheless the visual result is like the screen were cut at half.

Comment: Are you using wayland? I also have Debian 9.5, but without a fancy environment like gnome or kde (just xorg and a simple wm), so it'll take me a while to reproduce your setup.

Comment: I've checked and my system is running x11, should I shift to Wayland?

Comment: No, I'm using xorg too. I'll try to reproduce your setup and I'll update the answer later in the day.

Comment: If you're ok with using `mate` instead of `gnome3` you could try my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Comment: I downloaded a live image with mate as desktop environment but I get the same result when I run `xrandr --fb 800x768`. I don't know what else I could try, It has to be something related to my graphic card.

Comment: You should have tried the commands given in the "Update" part on your debian 9.5 -- they're not destructive; if it didn't work, you could've just removed the two files created (`rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98-no_xrr /etc/X11/no_xrr.so`) and uninstall mate (`apt-get remove --purge mate-desktop-environment`). But I'll try to have the hack work with gnome3/mutter too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my modified version of that script ( with KDE changes found elsewhere )

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# (if using as a KDE autostart script)
# sleep 10

# change these 4 variables accordingly
ORIG_X=2880
ORIG_Y=1800
NEW_X=2810
NEW_Y=1800
###
#Modify to multiple of 8. Issues with window sizing etc without these next two lines.
NEW_X=$(($NEW_X/8*8))
NEW_Y=$(($NEW_Y/8*8))
X_DIFF=$(($NEW_X - $ORIG_X))
Y_DIFF=$(($NEW_Y - $ORIG_Y))
# Uncomment the next line to use left portion of screen:
#X_DIFF=0
# Uncomment the next line to use upper portion of screen:
#Y_DIFF=0

ORIG_RES="$ORIG_X"x"$ORIG_Y"
NEW_RES="$NEW_X"x"$NEW_Y"
ACTIVEOUTPUT=$(xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/")
MODELINE=$(cvt $NEW_X $NEW_Y | grep Modeline | cut -d' ' -f3-)

xrandr --newmode $NEW_RES $MODELINE
xrandr --addmode $ACTIVEOUTPUT $NEW_RES
xrandr --output $ACTIVEOUTPUT --fb $NEW_RES --panning $NEW_RES --mode $NEW_RES
xrandr --fb $NEW_RES --output $ACTIVEOUTPUT --mode $ORIG_RES --transform 1,0,$X_DIFF,0,1,$Y_DIFF,0,0,1

# KDE specific -- restart shell so that icon tray is properly sized
# kquitapp5 plasmashell
# kstart5 plasmashell
```

[SDDM](https://github.com/sddm/sddm):

To have this take effect at the sddm login screen put an echo in front of each xrandr line then copy the resulting xrandr commands into the sddm startup. **If you are running KDE you will need to disable KScreen to carry over the settings into KDE Plasma.**

With your display connected run...

```bash
grep "Manufacturer:" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

...  to look up the display in your /var/log/Xorg.0.log and modify the if grep line below accordingly.
Don't forget to change the xrandr lines as mentioned above.
Add to your /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup:

```bash
if grep -q -wi "Manufacturer: SKY  Model: 1801" /var/log/Xorg.0.log; then
  xrandr --newmode 2872x2160 531.25 2872 3104 3416 3960 2160 2163 2173 2237 -hsync +vsync
  xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 2872x2160
  xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --fb 2872x2160 --panning 2872x2160 --mode 2872x2160
  xrandr --fb 2872x2160 --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 3840x2160 --transform 1,0,-968,0,1,0,0,0,1
fi
```