# Reduce size of my screen with a command line

Tags: debian, command-line, display, resolution, size

I am running a Debian stable with Cinnamon graphical interface 3.6.7 and my computer is connected to a multimedia projector. I havea an Intel Graphic card.

The projected image is too big and I can't change neither the place of my multimedia projector nor the place of my wall to reduce the size of the projected image.

Thus I would like to find a command line so that the resolution of the projected image is the same but such that a black band is at the border of my screen (see Figures below). I expect then that the projected image will have a smaller size.

**Solution** (@Ipor Sircer)

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --fb 1620x880
```

**Current configuration:**
[image: Current configuration]

**Expected configuration**
[image: Expected configuration]

Comment: You may look at xrandr tool to manage you display & resolution etc...

Comment: What model projector do you have? I have found that you can possible change your settings to reduce the "overscan" as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526836/how-to-set-screen-borders-for-hdmi-output) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv). Or do you prefer a command line solution?

Comment: I would prefer command line solution but I will have a look to overscan with the projector settings

Comment: @Smilia, I would check out the `xrandr` command with the `--transform` option [listed here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=261195) if you are set on using command line. You will have to play around with the exact parameters to get what you desire. Again, I would check for "Overscan" or "Screen Fit" or "Aspect Ratio" settings on the projector itself to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `xrandr` to detect the default output. Then you can make a black border:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --set underscan on --set "underscan vborder" 100 --set "underscan hborder" 100
```

(not working with intel graphic card)

Comment: ok thanks I ran this command:

$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --set underscan on --set "underscan vborder" 100 --set "underscan hborder" 100

Comment: I get the error: X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)

Comment: Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  47

Comment: Which video driver do you use? Not all supports this, only AMD and NVIDIA.

Comment: Oh yeah I have intel ...

Comment: Then you can play with various `--transform` parameters. I have no experience with this.

Comment: It's a related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472459/xrandr-problem-trying-to-avoid-broken-display