# How to determine what entity changes Xorg DPI settings?

Tags: linux, xorg, xfce, dpi, high-dpi

I've installed Xubuntu 19.04, and to account for my laptop's screen resolution, in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` I've added the line

```
xserver-command=X -dpi 166
```

The result is that XFCE panel, terminal and other GTK2 and GTK3 programs take on the correct font sizes (the same as if I had set *Custom DPI setting* in *Appearance*→*Fonts* to 166), but all the others like e.g. Yakuake still see 96 DPI. Moreover, if I try `xdpyinfo`, I do get this 96 DPI:

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep dot
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Also, if I tick and untick back the *Custom DPI setting* option, the fonts shrink back in XFCE too (apparently, DPI gets re-queried from X server).

So I suspect that, during session startup, some entity changes the screen DPI setting as if by running `xrandr --dpi 96`. If I manually run `xrandr --dpi 166`, programs start behaving correctly.

I'd like to find out what exactly entity is doing this, so as to fix this at the core instead of adding post-startup workarounds. How can I find it?

Comment: That's an [ugly story](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705) (read towards its end about `Xft.dpi` and other workarounds). If you're NOT using multiple monitors with diverse resolutions, you can put this in your `~/.xsession` or other startup script (depending on your config): `xrandr --fbmm "$(xrandr | sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]*\)mm x \([0-9]*\)mm.*/\1x\2/p')"; xdpyinfo | sed -n 's/.*x\(.*\) dots per inch/Xft.dpi: \1/p' | xrdb -merge -nocpp`

Comment: @mosvy that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid: workarounds. Xorg is already starting with correct DPI (I've checked that by `startx /usr/bin/xterm -- -dpi 166`, as well as by the default font sizes in XFCE). It's just some bad X client that resets it to 96.

Comment: I'm using my own wm (not some fancy DE), and I cannot check it just know, but I think that gnome or kde may reset the display resolution (using xrandr) to match `Xft.dpi`, which they assume that it "should" be 96 dpi if not set.

Comment: @mosvy OK, running `xrdb -merge -nocpp <<< 'Xft.dpi: 166'` results in Yakuake having larger fonts after `xfce4-session` is run, but `xdpyinfo` still outputs the reset value of 96, and ticking&unticking _Custom DPI setting_ in XFCE _Appearance_ dialog still shrinks XFCE fonts. Same with the case when I force `xrandr --fbmm` as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to comments by @mosvy, I've found that the culprit is `xfsettingsd`. In particular, its [`xfce_displays_helper_normalize_crtc`](https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-settings/blob/88280077fa183c1241c6d7b4e80ecd3ca6a43697/xfsettingsd/displays.c#L1247) function contains this arbitrary hard-coded choice of 96 DPI:

```c
    /* The 'physical size' of an X screen is meaningless if that screen
     * can consist of many monitors. So just pick a size that make the
     * dpi 96.
     *
     * Firefox and Evince apparently believe what X tells them.
     */
    helper->mm_width = (helper->width / 96.0) * 25.4 + 0.5;
    helper->mm_height = (helper->height / 96.0) * 25.4 + 0.5;
```

After I stubbed this function away in the binary by replacing its first byte with `0xC3` (x86/x86_64 `RET` instruction), I no longer have 96 DPI forced on me.

This is not a fully long-term solution though, because an upgrade can overwrite this file, so I either have to hold `xfce4-settings` package (by `apt-mark hold xfce4-settings`), or do something else to avoid this misbehavior.

Comment: You can also use a `LD_PRELOAD` hack to override `XRRSetScreenSize`. See this [old answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472472/308316) for an example, including for how you could sneak `LD_PRELOAD` accross `ssh-agent` in the `/etc/Xsession.d` startup scripts. Yes, I know, that's not much better ;-)